# configure 1and1 mail on google cloud platform with laravel 5

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, google-cloud-platform

I have setup an instance in google cloud platform. I am running laravel 5.2 project on that instance. Everything is working good but i am facing some issues while configuring 1and1 mail.

I know that google cloud platform is blocked the 587,465 and 25 port by default and we can setup some vpn which will help to remove this restriction. But i don't want to go in that way because it would have security problems.

I have tried to send email through smtp and mail driver. I am getting connection failure error through smtp driver, and through mail driver, it shows that email is sent but i am not getting the email in my inbox. Here is my .env file for mail driver settings for 1and1. I have also tried 25 port also.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=test@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Can you please help me to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

As you alluded to, and [documented](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/), GCE doesn't allow outbound 25, 465 or 587. This is blocking your connection to 1and1.

If you can ask 1and1 to provide an alternate SMTP port (e.g. 2525 etc) then you can use that without issue.

Google also has partners that will allow you to send up to tens of thousands of emails monthly, for free. Pick one and follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#whats_next).